# video.watches built-in type trouble

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-opengraph, watch

I have a trouble with built-in open graph action type video.watches. I develop an iOS app that should post video watch events. there are two watch action types in my apps' settings and code for them is:

1. [appnamespace]:watch
2. video.watches

first one is used for the web site. I need to use second one (not my wish but requirement of the client). To approve the second one I have to provide the test environment to show^ how it works but I have some troubles with it, because app with OpenGraph is not in app store and also it allows watching content only in Russia territory.

So I have couple questions for those who is familiar with Open Graph:

1. Is it possible to use video.watches request to post actions or facebook requires using request like [appnamespace]:watch for all approved actions?
2. If the first question answer is "Yes it's possible", what should I do to provide the test environment? I mean, should I connect with any support (and how to do that?) to provide the test app version?